# Gathering video data in Python

Tags: python, video, screen, frame

I am wanting to create a project that takes video data from a simple 2-D video game, and when a certain object appears on the screen it will press a key to move out of the way.

I am wondering, how exactly do you grab a live video data in Python? Is that the best way to approach this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you suggesting the use of CV to recognize the object in question? Once you recognize the object, then you can automate the movement process.

Comment: My original idea was to grab the video from the screen and if there is an object 180 degrees ahead of you (maybe pixel color) to move out of the way. I am just looking for a project to get back into Python and sharpen my skills. What would you recommend? 

The game just involves a car traveling in a straight line. Cars and other objects appear on the screen and you have to press an arrow key to switch lanes and avoid hitting it.

Comment: I mean, this seems like a complicated scenario to get back into the swing of Python. That being said, I do not think it would be overly complicated. I say that in the sense that you are not really identifying the type of object, merely that there is an object in the path of the vehicle. You would need to account for background (i.e. the road, anything not on the road, etc.). Your scan would need to be quick enough to detect the object, then automate the movement out of the lane. I would think that you would not want to immediately change lanes upon detection of an object...

Comment: due to potentially detecting one object, moving into the other lane, detecting another object, and moving back into the lane you just left but that is not yet clear. Those are just some of the things I would think about.